# Redirecting bare domain to www doesn't when specifying http/https scheme

Tags: url, 301-redirect, https, http, error

I've recently uploaded a website on a domain via Firebase hosting. Using the domain registrar (NameCheap) I've also applied a 301 redirect rule (via NameCheap. It's called "URL redirect record" under the Host Records) so that going to "@" (for example `example.com`) will redirect to `www.example.com`.

However, I noticed that if I specify either http or https scheme like so - `http[s]://example.com` I get to `https://example.com` (even when entering http), and get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

What's the reason for that and how can it be fixed? Am I doing some things wrong?

I'll mention that at first the 301 rule did not work when I specified to go to `https://www.example.com`, and only after replacing the `https` with regular `http` did it work (although when visiting the site, I still see in the URL that it is in fact using https).

People have suggested HSTS (which is automatically added by Firebase) to be the cause for the issue, however, other websites (such as Facebook) have HSTS yet don't encounter the same problem.

Comment: When you say you implemented a redirect, did you do so through NameCheap or through the hosting company that hosts your main website?  I'm assuming your hosting company is something other than NameCheap.  Which company is it?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you're correct. I used Firebase for hosting, and the redirect is done through NameCheap. I updated my question to indicate that.

Comment: How about HSTS?   Are you trying to use that? (The answer is "no" if you don't know what it is or unless you have a `.dev` domain website.)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No. I didn't enable it. But maybe it's on by default with Firebase?

Comment: Yes, it appears that Firebase automatically adds HSTS to all hosted websites: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/S6XDEV6TVhk

Comment: But other websites (such as Facebook) have HSTS yet don't encounter the same problem. Furthermore, the problem also occurs when specifying an HTTPS scheme, rather than HTTP. So it seems that something else doesn't work for the redirection

Comment: Facebook and other domains that use HSTS also redirect their bare domain using HTTPS.

Comment: @O.Aroesti All HSTS does is _force_ HTTPS on the same hostname. There is no redirect from HTTP. The initial request goes straight to HTTPS (www or non-www). So, if you have a problem with HTTPS (www or non-www) then you'll have a problem with HSTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namecheap does not offer HTTPS for redirects.  It would be better to implement the redirect at your hosting company so that they can do HTTPS for the redirect. This page has instructions about half way down for adding both www and no-www to Firebase and setting one to redirect to the other  https://www.allwebtuts.com/add-a-custom-domain-on-google-firebase-hosting/

Redirecting `http://example.com` to either `http://www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com` should work fine.   There are two reasons that you may be running into problems:

1. **Browser caching**:  Browsers aggressively cache 301 redirects.  If you change a 301 redirect you need to clear your browser cache before testing again.  Alternatively test with a online or command line tool.  I like using the command line: `curl --head http://example.com/`
2. **HSTS**:  HSTS is a directive to bypass HTTP for secuity.  It is a way of saying "my site will never ever use the insecure HTTP protocol".   When HSTS is enabled, browsers automatically upgrade all HTTP URLs to HTTPS after visiting your site for the first time.  So if HSTS is enabled, `http://example.com` will automatically get upgraded to `https://example.com` without hitting your server.  When you are using Namecheaps redirects without HTTPS, users will just get the connection refused error.

Comment: The resource you pointed only shows the Firebase checkbox option to redirect from subdomain to the naked domain (www.example.com › example.com). Could you elaborate on the way to do the contrary (www.example.com › example.com)? I see that in their example they end up with A records for both the naked domain and the subdomain, while the proper solution would be to redirect the naked domain to the "www" version, is it not?

Comment: I was assuming that you could add the bare domain and choose to redirect that.  I've never used Firebase myself, so I haven't tested it.

Comment: It seems like the problem was indeed browser caching. Opened in a different browser and incognito mode and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your web hosting provider is not running an HTTPS server on the IP address associated with their webserver. (As indicated by ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ). I posit that if this is a default Namecheap setup that this is something they would need to rectify, but they may not be in a position to do so due to the substantial added complexity https adds to hosting a redirect service.

It also sounds like their may be a (browser) caching issue going on - which could explain the eratic behaviour you talk about in your last paragraph. Try flushing your browser cache or using an alternative browser.